# Rails form that wraps individual forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider this setup.  In my `Blogs#index` page I can update each individual Blog record.  Here is what it looks like:

[image: blogs index]

And here is the code for it:

```
<h1>Listing Blogs</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><b>ID</b></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><b>Title</b></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><b>Actions</b></div>
</div>

<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  <%= form_for(blog) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <%= blog.id %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-success" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end  %>
  <br>
<% end  %>

<%= link_to 'New Blog', new_blog_path %>
```

Not too bad.  But now what I want to do is add a form that *wraps* these forms.  This form would allow you to select the blog objects you want and then posts to some controller, grabbing the `id` of each of the blog records you selected:

[image: select_box]

The above is just a mock up.  I don't know how to actually do it, and that is the problem.

The idea is that the user can submit two types of forms:

- The *wrapping* form, which posts the `ids` of the `blogs` that were selected
- Or one of the *wrapped* forms, which would just go to the `Blogs#update` action for that individual blog record you want to update.

Since I can't nest forms inside of other forms, the only way I can think of doing this is with javascript:

- Turn that button for the *wrapped form* into an ajax request
- When the `Do something with selected blogs` button is clicked, use javascript to see what the associated `blog id` is for each checked checkbox, add it to an array, and then call a `get` request along with the `blog ids` as parameters.

I would strongly prefer to not use javascript.  Is there any way that I could keep the same layout without using javascript, and which would allow me to post to a *wrapped* form, but also post any of the *individual* forms that are inside that wrapped form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  The key for me was to not nest the forms.  Instead: I just put the two *types* of forms *side-by-side*.  I did this by using bootstrap's grid system.

[image: outlining seperate forms]

And here is the code.  Note that it does use bootstrap for styling:

```
<h1>Listing Blogs</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <p>Select</p>
      <%= form_tag do_something_blogs_path  do %>
        <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
          <div>
            <%= check_box_tag "blog_ids[]", blog.id, false %>
          </div><br>
        <% end  %>
        <%= submit_tag "Do Something with Selection" %>
      <% end  %>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"><p>ID</p></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Title</p></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Actions</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
        <%= form_for(blog) do |f| %>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= blog.id %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= f.label :title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-success" %>
          </div>
        <% end  %>
        <br><br>
      <% end  %>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<%= link_to 'New Blog', new_blog_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest answer would be to have duplicate fields for each item (depending on what you need) and set the duplicate to hidden. Then the javascript you need to write is copying the the data from the non-hidden form into the hidden one whenever any of the fields you care about are changed. This way you can have your 2nd form below the one above and it will appear like its just the button, as in your mockup.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been tested:

```
#routes
post "update_all" => "blogs#update_all"
```

And

```
#view
<%= form_tag "/update_all", method: "post" do %>
  <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <%= form_for @blog do |f| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= select_tag "blog_ids[]", blog.id %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= blog.id %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.label :title %>
          <%= f.text_field :title %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= f.submit "Update Blog", class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Do something with selected blogs", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

And.

```
#controller
def update
  #your standard update
end

def update_all
  #handle update all
end
```

I would check the server logs to see what gets passed overall and write a custom strong parameters function to sift through it.